# Restkit and opencv2 framework

Tags: ios, opencv, restkit

In my project in using `restkit` to connect to the webservice and I need to use `opencv` for image processing. Currently I have integrated restkit and having linker flag for it as `-all_load and -ObjC` in build settings which working fine. Now I integrate the opencv2 and it is giving me the linker error. if i remove the `all_load` and `-Objc` linker flag it is working fine but restkit is not sending the request.

Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all_load and -ObjC flags. Instead, add `force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libRestKit.a`

It should work.